# Problema ao iniciar programa java com o windows

Tags: java, windows

Explicações importantes:

- Tenho um aplicativo criado em JAVA;
- Foi criado um executável "EXE" utilizando o Launch4J;
- Tenho a necessidade de executar este aplicativo após a inicialização do windows.

**PRIMEIRA TENTATIVA**

Foi criado um atalho em `C:\Users\Elfab\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Esta opção não se mostrou eficiente, com o meu aplicativo.

**SEGUNDA TENTATIVA**

Foi criada uma entrada nos registros do windows nas chaves abaixo

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

**PROBLEMA**

As opções acima não se mostraram eficientes, porém com outros aplicativos este método se mostrou eficiente. O programa não inicia e não gera LOG de erros

**PERGUNTA**

1. Existem outras formas de se fazer um aplicativo iniciar com o windows?
2. Programas java precisam da JVM para funcionar, pode isto ser um problema de dependência da JVM? pode a JVM não ter iniciado antes de tentar abrir meu aplicativo java?
3. Caso o problema de dependência exista, tem alguma forma de iniciar o aplicativo somente após a JVM possuir suas dependências inicializadas?

Comment: E o que seria uma solução que "se mostre eficiente"? Qual é o problema das formas que tentou?

Comment: @renan desculpe se não ficou claro, o problema é que o aplicativo não inicia e nem gera LOG de erros. Uma solução eficiente é uma que consiga iniciar o aplicativo com o windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Existem outras formas de se fazer um aplicativo iniciar com o windows?**

A forma mais indicada disso no Windows é usar o Agendador de Tarefas, ele tem uma aplicação de linha de comando ([Schtasks.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) que permite criar e remover tarefas, e elas podem ser agendadas para iniciar na inicialização, basta sua aplicação, ou instalador, executar o comando com os argumentos que você precisa.

**Programas java precisam da JVM para funcionar, pode isto ser um problema de dependência da JVM? pode a JVM não ter iniciado antes de tentar abrir meu aplicativo java?**

Normalmente não, quando uma aplicação Java se inicia ela carrega a JVM, não é preciso iniciar a JVM antes. Mas eu não sei se tem alguma coisa diferente no caso de usar o Launch4J

**Caso o problema de dependência exista, tem alguma forma de iniciar o aplicativo somente após a JVM possuir suas dependências inicializadas?**

Vide resposta anterior, não deveria ser necessário iniciar o Java antes de rodar uma aplicação.

Comment: Consegui utilizar o Agendador de Tarefas para fazer funcionar, mas apenas manualmente, através de código java ainda não consegui inserir novas tarefas no windows. Porém tenho uma solução temporária.